# I want to redirect to another page when user click image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image

i created a gallery and i want when user click a image then it will redirect to another page as well as new page display full details of that particular image ! how to do it in node js and mongoDB.

This is my index.ejs page where i displayed my images.

```
        <% if(files) { %>
             <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
                 <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                   <% if(file.isImage){ %>
                     <a href="/checkout/<%=file.filename %>"><img src="image/<%=file.filename %>" alt="" ></a>
                     <span><%= file.metadata.username %></span><br>
                        <span><%= file.metadata.age %></span>
                   <% } else {%>
                        <p>Error</p>
                     <% } %>
                 </div>
              <% }) %>
        <% } else { %>
              <p>No files to show </p>
        <% } %>
```

route file

```
 app.get('/checkout/:filename', (req,res) => {
     res.redirect('/solo', { pic: req.params.filename });
 });
```

Comment: Wrap the image in a link (`<a href>`) element, implement the new page. (More details in answer would require more details in question.)

Comment: can you plz check my codes

Comment: At a glance, that's what you should be doing. So... what exactly does not work, and in which exact way? (And also, obviously, do you have a handler for the `/checkout/:filename` route?)

Comment: yes i have route file for them ! i created website wherein there's many images on the page and when i click one of the image it must be shown into another page with full details.. but the problem i don't know how to do it ? plz check my route file

Comment: Please reread what I said. How _exactly_ does it not do what you want? What you've done should work, unless I'm missing a detail, and I don't feel like going over each character blind. You need to tell me what to look for. You stated what you want to be done. You need to also explain what is happening _now_. How does the actual state differ from the desired state? What happens when you click the image? Do you end up on another URL? Which one? What is shown there? What do you expect to have shown there? By which code? Is there an error by node.js? If so, which?

Comment: Could you plz check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326997/image-is-not-display